# Node.js make initialized object available in all modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an initialized object that I initialized in app.js file and I would like to make this initialized object is available in all modules. How could I do that? Passing this object to every modules is one way to do and I'm wondering if I'm missing anything or there should be done in difference ways?

I saw mongoose actually support default connection, which I need to init in app.js one time and anywhere in other modules, I can just simply use it without requiring passing it around. Is there any I can do the same like this?

I also checked global object doc from node.js http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html, and wondering I should use global for issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A little advice:

- You should only very rarely need to use a global. If you think you need one, you probably don't.
- Singletons are usually an anti-pattern in Node.js, but sometimes (logging, config) they will get the job done just fine.
- Passing something around is sometimes a useful and worthwhile pattern.

Here's an example of how you might use a singleton for logging:

lib/logger.js

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan'),
  mixIn = require('mout/object/mixIn'),

  // add some default options here...
  defaults = {},

  // singleton
  logger,

  createLogger = function createLogger(options) {
    var opts;

    if (logger) {
      return logger;
    }

    opts = mixIn({}, defaults, options);

    logger = bunyan.createLogger(opts);

    return logger;
  };

module.exports = createLogger;
```

lib/module.js

```
var logger = require('./logger.js'),
  log = logger();

log.info('Something happened.');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Elliott, Singleton pattern will do the job!. Cool!

Comment: Just a note to nodejs beginners this is also acceptable: `var log = require('./logger.js')()`

Answer (score 4):

The solution, as you suggest is to add the object as a property to the global object.  However, I would recommend against doing this and placing the object in its own module that is `require`d from every other module that needs it.  You will gain benefits later on in several ways.  For one, it is always explicit where this object comes from and where it is initialized.  You will never have a situation where you try to use the object before it is initialized (assuming that the module that defines it also initializes it).  Also, this will help make your code more testable,

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to the problem, depends upon how large your application is. The two solutions that you have mentioned are the most obvious ones. I would rather go for the third which is based on re-architecturing your code. The solution that I am providing looks alot like the executor pattern.

First create actions which require your common module that are in this particular form -

```
var Action_One = function(commonItems) {
    this.commonItems = commonItems;
};

Action_One.prototype.execute = function() {
    //..blah blah
    //Your action specific code
};


var Action_Two = function(commonItems) {
    this.commonItems = commonItems;
};

Action_Two.prototype.execute = function() {
    //..blah blah
    //Your action_two specific code
};
```

Now create an action initializer which will programmatically initialize your actions like this -

```
var ActionInitializer = function(commonItems) {
    this.commonItems = commonItems;
};

ActionInitializer.prototype.init = function(Action) {
    var obj = new Action(this.commonItems);
    return obj;
};
```

Next step is to create an action executor -

```
//You can create a more complex executor using `Async` lib or something else
var Executor = function(ActionInitializer, commonItems) {
    this.initializer = new ActionInitializer(commonItems);
    this.actions = [];
};
//Use this to add an action to the executor
Executor.prototype.add = function(action) {
    var result = this.initializer.init(action);
    this.actions.push(result);
};
//Executes all the actions 
Executor.prototype.executeAll = function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = this.action.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[i] = this.action[i].execute();
    }
    this.action = []
    return result;
};
```

The idea was to decouple every module so that there is only one module `Executor` in this case which is dependent on the common properties. Now lets see how it would work -

```
var commonProperties = {a:1, b:2};
//Pass the action initilizer class and the common property object to just this one module
var e = new Executor(ActionInitializer, commonProperties);
e.add(Action_One);
e.add(Action_Two);
e.executeAll();
console.log(e.results);
```

This way your program will be cleaner and more scalable. Shoot questions if it's not clear. Happy coding!

Comment: will take me times to digest this solution. I will keep you posted if it works for me. I'm sure it should work. Thanks.

Comment: Sure let me know if you don't understand something.

Comment: This is similar to a facade pattern, only in this case, it's a monolithic facade, instead of a facade for a very focussed bit of functionality. I don't recommend this approach for Node applications, because it hides dependencies. It's harder to tell which modules are dependent on which other modules (which is the whole point of the pattern). That can be as much of a curse as it is a blessing.

I do recommend that you use patterns like this to abstract specific types of needs -- such as hiding database access behind a data domain abstraction, etc...

Comment: @EricElliott I think you are right. Could give some sample code to explain your point of view better?

Comment: @Tushar Well, I don't think it's easy to explain with example code, but the idea is that if you use a facade for all your shared stuff, the facade itself can grow to the point of being unmanageable. It will develop into a frankenstein hierarchy over time for non-trivial applications, where you have categories and sub-categories of objects and utility functions. Eventually the facade itself needs to be split to clean up the mess because it's too monolithic.

Comment: You also get a bunch of implicit dependencies in your module. Your module relies on a string-handling module, but you can't tell because it's hiding behind a facade, say, app.helpers.stringUtil(). Later you refactor and remove the string module. Another developer can't figure out why his module that depends on app.helpers.stringUtil() broke.

Explicit module imports don't suffer from that problem.

Comment: @EricElliott, Thanks for your feedback, is this something that you can blog if you have a chance? This seems to be interesting issue and how to solve it.

Comment: There's a good discussion of the Facade Pattern on Wikipedia, but that is a good idea for a blog post. Specifically, some tips on when to use it, and when not to use it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern